# How to get the group name and index list in a grouped pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I want the equivalent of this pandas code in pyspark. The following pandas code generates the atable names and the indexes where the atable name is found:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'atable':     ['Users', 'Users', 'Domains', 'Domains', 'Locks'],
    'column':     ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col'],
    'column_type':['varchar', 'varchar', 'int', 'varchar', 'varchar'],
    'is_null':    ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
})

df1_grouped = df1.groupby('atable')

# iterate over each group
for group_name, df_group in df1_grouped.groups.items():
    print(group_name, df_group)
```

Output:

```
Domains Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')
Locks Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')
Users Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

The spark output should look like this:

```
#+-------+--------------------+
#|atable |             sources|   
#+-------+--------------------+
#|Domains|    [2, 3]          |
#|Locks  |     [4]            |
#| Users |    [0, 1]          |
#+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: note - spark does not have indices and neither does it retain the dataframe's order -- due to its distributed nature. If able, look into the [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) which lets you write pandas-style code on a spark dataframe (the pyspark-pandas dataframe is actually a spark dataframe behind the scenes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by samkart there is no intrinsic order in a Spark dataframe. If you want to retain the information which row in the original dataframe went into which group during the grouping operation, you can use [monotonically_increasing_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html) to assign a unique id to each row in the original dataframe and then use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) as aggregation function:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=spark.createDataFrame(df1)

df.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .groupBy('atable') \
    .agg(F.collect_list('id')) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
|atable |collect_list(id)          |
+-------+--------------------------+
|Domains|[17179869184, 25769803776]|
|Users  |[0, 8589934592]           |
|Locks  |[25769803777]             |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

The IDs created by `monotonically_increasing_id` are unique but not sequential. There are some *hacks* to create sequential ids ([here](https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62268499/2129801)) but usually these approaches are not a good idea as a unique sequential id does not fit well into Spark's distributed nature.